# Recording MediaPlayer Sound

Tags: javafx, mp3, media

I am developing a simple Mp3Player with JavaFX, and using MediaPlayer class to do the job, I am being quite sucessful with it, however I'd like to record the equalized sound I get from media player object to  another .mp3 file. Is there anyway  to do that?

Comment: What have you already tried? Can you show the code?

Comment: JavaFX only has media playback capabilities, not recording capabilities, so you would need to use another library to create a new equalized .mp3 file.  I  have not used other media APIs enough to advise on a library (advising on libraries is outside the scope of StackOverflow anyway).

Comment: For now, I just set the playback and equalization capabilites,  now I am looking for some way to get the equalized mp3,  i found some java SE libraries that can interact with the audio inputs from the PC, maybe it can get me output too, but  i haven't tried it yet.